# How to read a string separated by spaces in C++?

Tags: c++, string

The user introduces a string like "1 10 4 1 53" and I have to read all the numbers in the string. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: This and similar questions have been covered countless times here; did you try searching?

Comment: The keywords are "StackOverflow C++ read file integers space separated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If speed is not what you care, use `stringstream`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main()
{
  string str("1 10 4 1 53");
  stringstream ss(str);
  int n;
  while (ss >> n)
    cout << n << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it into a [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use normal `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take input as a string and then you can tokenize the string using [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to separate the string.

Comment: 1980 called; they want their string tokenisation techniques back... (that's _thirty-four_ years ago!!)